# No way to stream HTTP Response on React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I've discovered that Native Fetch does not allow streaming objects.
SO I've installed 'react-native-community' & Polyfill. This has solved the issue for iOS.

On Android Development it almost works. It does not seem to update the stream in realtime, but this is a known issue specificaly in Development Mode (https://github.com/react-native-community/fetch/issues/13)

I'm reading that it should work fine in Build. When I go to create my Preview Build on Android, ALL fetch() requests fail. Even non-streaming ones. It generates no error on adb logcat. But I know the requests are being made because I can see my backend server sending 200 responses.

I know the culprit is polyfill/community-fetch, because when I remove polyfill regular fetch() requests work (but streaming do not obviously).

Is there any solution to getting remote http text streaming to work on Android? I don't want to create web sockets.

```
 "expo": "~49.0.15",
 "react": "18.2.0",
 "react-native": "0.72.6",
```